# How to initialize a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My understanding is that a function in JavaScript can have states. Some states need to be initialized just once. How do you do that so that calling the function does not re-initialize them?

For example, `$()` in jQuery is a function, not an object, and yet it seems to have states and act like an object.

I thought about creating an object for this, but what I want is really a facade function, much like the way `$()` works.

Comment: Define "function with state". `function f() {}; f.x = 0;` works, but the rest of the question doesn't read like you talk about that.

Comment: Functions are objects, too, as is pretty much everything in JavaScript.

Comment: @janmoesen: Except primitive variables (strings, numbers, booleans) and the primitives `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @janmoesen - ...but not quite everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Functions** are *objects*. They can have properties:

```
function F() {}
F.key = "value";
alert(F.key) // "value"
```

You can also use functions as *constructors* called with **`new`**:

```
function F(val) { this.key = val; }
var instance = new F("value")
alert(instance.key) // "value"
```

The difference as you can see is that the first version only adds a `key` memeber to the `F` function object, while the second one initializes a new `key` member on every *instance* created by **`new`**`F`.

When you call a function via **`new`** an *instance* object is automatically created and can be augmented by the `this` keyword. Every constructor returns `this` by default.

You can also add public methods to the function's `prototype`, and they will be available for all the *instances*. They can change their "state" (as you call it) individually using the `this` keyword.

```
function F(val) { this.state = val; } // unique
F.prototype.change = function() { this.state = "stuff"; } 

var inst  = new F("value")
var inst2 = new F("value")

alert(inst.state)  // "value"
alert(inst2.state) // "value"

inst.change();

alert(inst.state)  // "stuff"
alert(inst2.state) // "value"
```

---

> **jQuery**

I can even tell you what jQuery is doing behind the scenes, but I don't think you really want to know. :)

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    },

// ...

jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    init: function( selector, context ) {
       // ...
    },
    // ...
};

// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

So basically `$(selector)` means **`new`**`jQuery.fn.init(selector)`, it's just a shortcut for easier typing (and also to prevent the "bug" mentioned in the comments where fogetting **`new`** binds  `this` to the *global object*, instead of the current instance).

Also, the so-called plug-ins added as `jQuery.fn.ext` are mapped to `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` as you can see in the last line, it's another shortcut. So when you call `$(selector)` everything that is added to `jQuery.fn` will also be on `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` and so the new instance will have those methods as `$(selector).ext(...)`.

```
// as you use it today
jQuery.fn.plugin = function ( ... ) { ... }
$(selector).plugin( ... )

// as it would be without shortcuts
jQuery.fn.init.prototype.plugin = function ( ... ) { ... }
(new jQuery.fn.init(selector)).plugin( ... )
```

Comment: it's worth noting that if you don't use the F function with new, this.key will refer to the global this.

Comment: Thank you! Just curious though - why did they make it "var jQuery = function(selector, context)" instead of "function jQuery(selector, context)"?

Comment: @Tom Tucker - It would be another long story :) But honestly, I don't thing you need to imitate the design of jQuery. Go with something more simple, and pleasant looking. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict a function from be called more than once, i suggest you implement the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is fully object oriented, prototype-based language. And by fully I mean everything is an object including arrays, numbers and so-called functions:

```
var number = 32.1245;
alert(number.toFixed(2)); // 32.12
```

Basically when you define a function using `function` keyword you're actually defining a [object constructor](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml). Inside object constructor you can define object's *public* properties using `this`:

```
function Car(model) {
   this.model = model;
   this.productionYear = new Date().getFullYear();
}

var car = new Car("Audi A8");
car.productionYear = 2009;
```

Of course those properties can be objects constructors as well.

Comment: The contents of your constructor are useless and misleading.

Comment: @Crozin - `typeof 32.1245` ? There are primitives in the language that are not objects.

Comment: @galambalazs: No, it's not a primitive (JS doesn't have such), it's an object - [Number object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp) to be precise.

Comment: @Crozin - *ECMA-262 5th Edition* - " **4.3.2 primitive value** - member of one of the types `Undefined`, `Null`, `Boolean`, `Number`, or `String` as defined Clause 8. *NOTE: A primitive value is a datum that is represented directly at the lowest level of the language implementation.* "

Comment: @Crozin - btw w3Schools is rather old (and bad) but it's not mistaken when it says *"The Number object is an **object wrapper for primitive** numeric values."* - Thus of course `typeof Number(32)` is `object`, but `typeof 32` is still `number`, because it's a primitive value.